# Changing the tab colour according to the click

Tags: android, tabs, android-actionbar

I have implemented the tab bar as shown in the below image

1. I want to change it as shown in the images
2. Tab highlighter should be black and the selected tab image should be highlighted in black others in grey. (fyp I have back and grey images).

[image]

Comment: Nice post but please post you code here for quick and efficient answers.

Comment: I followed this tutorial, can you refer this 

http://www.androidhive.info/2013/10/android-tab-layout-with-swipeable-views-1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a drawable with active and inactive images.

```
mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("").setIndicator("",getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.name_of_xml)),
                DemoClass.class, null);
```

Here is XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/active_black_dark" android:state_pressed="false" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/inactive_black_light"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: it gave me this when i tried, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo: java.lang.NullPointerException